# Carousel not working after adding items dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I added images dynamically to carousel but they weren't worked. I only got images but not carousel format. this my code as shown below.

```
<div id="summeritems" class="popular-products-slides owl-carousel">
    <!-- Single Product -->

    <!-- End -->
</div>
```

// Jquery Code

```
items.forEach(function(item){
var result =  `<div class="single-product-wrapper">
 <div class="product-img">
  <img src="/image/${item.filename}" alt="">
  <div class="product-favourite">
    <a href="#" class="favme fa fa-heart"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-description">
  <span>${item.metadata.brand}</span>
  <a href="single-product-details.html">
    <h6>${item.metadata.name}</h6>
  </a>
  <p class="product-price">LKR. 
  ${item.metadata.price}</p>
  <div class="hover-content">
    <!-- Add to Cart -->
    <div class="add-to-cart-btn">
      <a href="#" class="btn essence-btn">Add to 
      Cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>`
$('#summeritems').append(result); // Add Images to Navigation Slider
```

Comment: Did you try `owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel')`? If you will publish your code by Snippets will be easier help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    items.forEach(function(item){

              v = '/image/'+item.filename;
              image_temp = new Image();
              image_temp.src = v;
              image_temp.onload = function(){
         $('#owl-sunny').owlCarousel().trigger('add.owl.carousel',
         [jQuery('<div class="owl-item"><a href="/'+ item.filename +'"><img src="'+ v +'"></a><div class="product-description"><span>' + item.metadata.brand + '</span><a href=""><h6>'+ item.metadata.name + '</h6></a><p class="product-price">LKR. ' + item.metadata.price + '</p></div></div>')]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your carousel after adding new elements. Like this:

```
var owl = $('#summeritems');
owl.owlCarousel();

// Your code
items.forEach(function(item){
  var result =  '... HTML of new elements ...';
  $('#summeritems').append(result); // Add Images to Navigation Slider
});

// update carousel at the end
owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

For more API official documentation is pretty helpful: [Owl carousel API](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

Comment: Thanks for Your reply ! but i didn't help me ! anyways i got a solution for this issue

Comment: @Harish You are welcome. You can answer your own question, so it will be useful for other viewers.